# C++ using typedef shared_ptr<Class> Shared as a type of field - member of another class

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef, shared

I have to classes, by exmaple class A and class B. Class A include B and B include A. Class A has typedef shared_ptr Shared, in class B I need to declare field-member type of A::Shared.

```
#include "B.h"
class A {
public:
    typedef shared_ptr<A> Shared;
};

#include "A.h"
class A;
class B {
public:
    A::Shared mA;
};
```

IDE says that can't resolve type Shared.

**SOLVED**
Remove #include directive from both headers, and use forward declaration.

```
class B;
class A {
public:
    typedef shared_ptr<A> Shared;
};

class A;
class B {
public:
    A::Shared mA;
};
```

Comment: Why do you include B.h in A.h?

Comment: @W.F. it's may be a problem ?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies

Comment: Yup its most probably it...